# how to use C++ singleton in objective-C?

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I need to use a C++ singleton in ViewController,and got error.

TradeAPIManager.h

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    class TradeAPIManager{
    public:
        static TradeAPIManager * getInstance();
            void test();
    private:
        TradeAPIManager(){}
        static TradeAPIManager *m_pInstance;
    };
```

TradeAPIManager.cpp

```
#include "TradeAPIManager.h"
TradeAPIManager *TradeAPIManager::m_pInstance = nullptr;
TradeAPIManager *TradeAPIManager::getInstance(){
    if(m_pInstance == nullptr){
        m_pInstance = new TradeAPIManager();
    }
    return m_pInstance;
}

void test(){
    printf("asdasd");
}
```

ViewController.mm

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    TradeAPIManager *manager = TradeAPIManager::getInstance();
    manager->test();
}
```

when build,i got error like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "TradeAPIManager::test()", referenced from:
      -[ViewController viewDidLoad] in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 in simulator

Undefined symbols for architecture  arm64 in my iPhone

thats not a .a lib or a framework,just a cpp file write by myself
I tried six hours but have no way out.
hope anyone can help
many thanks

Comment: In TradeAPIManager.cpp, `void test...` should read `TradeAPIManager::test...`.  The clue is in the error message.

Comment: Paul answered it. In C++ void test() in .cpp is different than void TradeAPIManager::test()

You are trying to call TradeAPIManager::test() which you did not implement. Just rename void test() to void TradeAPIManager::test()